# Override styles for axes and legend dc.js

Tags: dc.js

I will like to override the style for charts in dc.js

I want to change, fonts, colors, font-weights, for axes, legends, and similar.

What is the best way to make this changes, without modifying the lib?

Answer (score 0):

#### Styles/elements that are not driven by data

Anything that is not driven by data is best modified by using CSS. I usually just use the browser's inspector/developer tools to determine the correct selectors to use, but you can also get some clues by looking at the [sass source for dc.css](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/style/dc.scss).

All of the visual attributes you list above fall in this category. Generally anything that is outside of the plot area is not data-driven.

Many of the visual attributes for things inside the chart are also not data-driven. For example, if you wanted to change the text labels inside the plot area, those styles all come from dc.css and are best modified with CSS.

#### Styles/elements that are driven by data

For changing anything that *is* data-driven, using a `pretransition` hook is going to be the best way - this fires after a render or redraw when all elements have been added or removed (but before they transition from old values to new values).

The form for this is

```
chart.on('pretransition', function(chart) {
    chart.select('something').attr(...);
});
```

where `something` is a selector like `rect.bar` - in-chart selectors [are starting to be documented in the Wiki](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/Chart-selectors).